# What is the height of this rectangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

What I need is a formula that Given {X,W,Z,A,B,C,D,V} you can Find {Y}

[image]

This is a problem that's stumped me for a while I wonder if any of you guys could solve it.

Note. The top corners of the black rectangles are at the center of the orange and blue rectangles.

Comment: Are the sides of the orange and blue rectangles perpendicular to that of the back ones?

Comment: @MathLover Yes they are.

Comment: @MathLover I edited it, I hope its helpful.

Comment: You say "orange and blue squares" but the blue object is certainly not  (necessarily) square: it's a rectangle. Is the orange object really a square? If that is so, I guess $A$ is the distance from the corner of the orange square to the corner of the blue rectangle touching it. Correct?

Comment: @Nick remember in math diagrams, the information is what matters not what it looks like. so it could be a square and I am just a vary bad artist. I made it rectangle so people would understand that the lengths might not be not the same.

Comment: That does not answer the question: is $A$ the side of the orange rectangle or the distance from its corner to the corner of the blue rectangle touching that side?

Comment: @Nick  Side $A$ is the full length of the orange rectangles side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is given in the figure below.
In particular,
$$Y = X\tan(V) + \frac{Z+B/2}{\cos(V)}+\frac{C}{2}\tan(V)+\frac{D}{2}.$$
[image]

Comment: technically Yannik got it first but you explained it better. :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is
$$Y=\tan(V)X + \frac{Z}{\cos(V)} + \frac{B}{2\cos(V)} + \frac{C\tan(V)}{2} + \frac{D}{2}.$$

Comment: thanks soooooo much!